# Trying to get a four weekly running forecast of our average m3 sold

Tags: mdx

[image]

I would like to get a running average m3 over the last four weeks of sales.

so far I have come up with the following MDX query but it doesn't seem to work

```
Avg
([Normal Calendar].[Calendar Hierarchy].[Cal Week].Lag(4) :
[Normal Calendar].[Calendar Hierarchy].[Cal Week],
[Measures].[Intake Ordered m3]
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think just using the `CURRENTMEMBER` function could help:

```
AVG
(
   [Normal Calendar].[Calendar Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER.Lag(4) :
   [Normal Calendar].[Calendar Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER
  ,[Measures].[Intake Ordered m3]
)
```

or maybe this:

```
AVG
(
   [Normal Calendar].[Calendar Hierarchy].[Cal Week].CURRENTMEMBER.Lag(4) :
   [Normal Calendar].[Calendar Hierarchy].[Cal Week].CURRENTMEMBER
  ,[Measures].[Intake Ordered m3]
)
```

Comment: If you remove Cal week the query seems to work, but it doesn't seem to give an accurate four weekly average. current member doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @JamesPalmer The calculations mentioned above should work. Can you share the complete query that you are using, plus provide some screen shots pointing out where the issue is.